how to install openpbs jobsheduler for ubuntu 22.04?
I have a workstation with two nodes, each having 24 physical cores (48 threads) and an NVIDIA RTX A2000 12GB GPU. I want to install the Portable Batch System (PBS) for running jobs.However, I attempted the installation, and the server wouldn't start. Additionally, it caused issues with the GPU drivers. Could someone help me resolve this? Also, if I successfully install PBS, will I still be able to use my system for normal daily tasks?
